# Who else can complete a task other than the 'Assigned to'?

Tags: permissions, tasks, workflow-tasks-list, task-assignment

Is there another permission level that would be able to complete a task that's assigned to someone else?  I've given a manager 'Full Control' and 'Approval permission on a task list and the associated list, but they still can't complete a task on behalf of others.

In this instance the manager needs to complete tasks if the 'assigned to' is away on holiday, or ill.

The only way I can see at present is to create several groups and assign the tasks to the group rather than the individual, but this isn't ideal.

Comment: This is the error that appears when trying to complete a task assigned to someone else: "Task update was not accepted. To edit a task associated with a workflow task process, you must be the person to whom the task is currently assigned."

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can change a task (Approve, Reject, Reassign) which is not assigned to you:

1. Have site collection admin permissions
2. Specify ownership of a task process in SharePoint designer

I will specify a way to do this with SharePoint designer. First, create a SharePoint group on your site, or use an existing group. In SharePoint designer, navigate to your workflow, and click the dropdown next to the approval process, then select properties. Then, select the Task Process Ownership and set the ownership to the group you previously created, or a group containing the individual you want to give task process ownership to.

Now the designated task process owner can Approve tasks for people!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm going to have to test this to see if it's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For more detailed explanation about the solution, visit https://mohitvash.wordpress.com/2018/04/05/reassign-a-workflow-task-task-update-was-not-accepted-to-edit-a-task-associated-with-a-workflow-task-process-you-must-be-the-person-to-whom-the-task-is-currently-assigned/